# custom bootstrap css for YII2 frontend

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

how can I use a custom CSS (obtained from a bootstrap HTML template) with yii2 framework frontend? (i'm using Yii advanced template)

things i tried and that didn't work:

- adding the path to the custom css file in `frontend\assets\AppAsset.php`
- replaced the `bootstrap-theme.css` file under `frontend\web\assets\e4f17951\css\`
- modified the `frontend\config\main.php` according to this [tutorial](http://webtips.krajee.com/override-bootstrap-css-js-yii-2-0-widgets/)

**EDIT:**

following the tutorial , i added this to main-local.php:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
             'sourcePath' => 'frontend/web',
             'css' => ['css/bootstrap.css', 'css/agency.css']
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

maybe something wrong with sourcePath?

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add details about why it didn't work (only for third)

Comment: i have added details ..

Answer (score 11):

You can edit your frontend web config file to point to your custom bootstrap.css. Note that the path is relative.

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'css' => [
                'bootstrap.css' => 'path/to/your/bootstrap.css'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

Comment: the bootstrap html template has the same bootstrap.css file than the YII app.   and the second file, 'agency.css' ,is the custom is the one i need, in top of the "original' bootstrap file.   PS: sorry for my english .

Answer (score 4):

you can actually edit the [`AppAsset.php`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/assets/AppAsset.php) file

```
<?php
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;
/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        // add your bootstrap or any other css file path
        // example
        'css/bootstrap.css',
        'css/agency.css',
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        // 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset', remove / comment this
        // as you don't want to use default bootstrap
    ];
}
```

it should solve your issue